# How to prevent accessing a view from a user in oracle

Tags: sql, security, user-controls, oracle10g

Can someone please tell me how to prevent access to a view from a specific user in the oracle?

I have created a view called SKU_O_DETAILS and created a new user as "non_admin" then given access to the view.

```
GRANT SELECT ON retailx.SKU_O_DETAILS TO non_admin;
```

retailx is my schema inside my schema I created the view as SKU_O_DETAILS.

Now I want to prevent accessing to the view by user 'non_admin'

Is there a way that I could achieve without dropping the user 'non_admin'?

Comment: `REVOKE SELECT ON retailx.SKU_O_DETAILS FROM non_admin`?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer suggested by @vvdl

```
REVOKE SELECT ON retailx.SKU_O_DETAILS FROM non_admin
```